# Complex closed loop integral (Cauchy Integral): Singularity lies on the countour.

Tags: complex-analysis

1. What happens when the singularity lies on the contour (The path of integration)?

What if the point lies on the circle?
What would be the answer for this question?
$\int_{|z|=3}\frac{z}{z-3}dz$

Comment: That the integral is divergent.

Comment: The answer may exist as a Cauchy principal value. That's what is usually implied in physics, where it occurs quite frequently, for instance in the linear theory of electromagnetic response. Intuitively, you just cut the residue value in proportion of the angle the contour makes at that point. Half if the contour has no corner there.